# Spring Boot 1.3.0 creates multiple ContextLoader definitions

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I have an application which uses Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE.

The production version is suppoed to run on a Tomcat server (AWS Elastic Beanstalk).
Most of the time, when I deploy the application, I get an error:

```
18-Nov-2015 14:40:30.301 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer@16a15bdb, com.example.ExampleApplication@529635d6, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@19b5e8a2]
18-Nov-2015 14:40:37.851 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
18-Nov-2015 14:40:49.148 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
```

Being a Spring Boot application, I do not even have `web.xml`.

My `ExampleApplication` looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JerseyAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Class<ExampleApplication> APPLICATION_CLASS = ExampleApplication.class;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(APPLICATION_CLASS, args);
    }

@Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(APPLICATION_CLASS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "<NONE>");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
//...
}
```

I have read that `servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "<NONE>");` might help, so I've added that, but it didn't.
I thought excluding `JerseyAutoConfiguration` will help, but it didn't.

The applications runs without any issue using the `spring-build:run` maven goal, or running the package directly from the command line.

I do not have `@EnableWebMVC' anywhere in my code. (Even if I have, the result is the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're hitting [this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4527). You can work around the problem by adding `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` to `ExampleApplication` so that it runs before Jersey's `SpringWebApplicationInitializer` and, therefore, has a chance to switch it off.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was my bad. I had an extra dependency on `spring-boot-starter-jersey`, which created its own ContextLoader.